# Jboss AS 7 - Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, ejb, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x

Im attempting to make use of dependency injection in Jboss AS 7 and im having huge difficulties.

I have setup a EAR which contains both a EJB jar and a war.

The war contains a richfaces web app.

Im attempting to inject an EJB from the ejb jar into a faces managed bean with the code below :

```
 public class UserController {

    @EJB(mappedName="UserService")
    private UserFacadeService userService;

    public String getService(){
        if(userService == null){
```

however when i deploy jboss puts the error in the console :

```
rolled back with failure message {"Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.subunit.\"GoodByeJohnEAR.ear\".\"GoodByeJohnWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"managed-bean.za.co.gbj.UserController\".START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.GoodByeJohnEAR.\"GoodByeJohnWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT\".\"env/za.co.gbj.UserController/userService\" ]","jboss.deployment.subunit.\"GoodByeJohnEAR.ear\".\"GoodByeJohnWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".jndiDependencyService missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.GoodByeJohnEAR.\"GoodByeJohnWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT\".\"env/za.co.gbj.UserController/userService\" ]","jboss.naming.context.java.module.GoodByeJohnEAR.\"GoodByeJohnWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT\".\"env/za.co.gbj.UserController/userService\".jboss.deployment.subunit.\"GoodByeJohnEAR.ear\".\"GoodByeJohnWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".module.GoodByeJohnEAR.\"GoodByeJohnWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT\".2 missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.GoodByeJohnEAR.\"GoodByeJohnWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT\".env/UserService ]"]}
09:03:50,576 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) Starting deployment of "GoodByeJohnEAR.ear"
09:03:50,670 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Starting deployment of "GoodByeJohnWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war"
09:03:50,670 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) Starting deployment of "GoodByeJohnEJB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
09:03:51,367 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.service-loader] (MSC service thread 1-2) Encountered invalid class name "com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider:org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor" for service type "com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider"
09:03:51,367 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.service-loader] (MSC service thread 1-2) Encountered invalid class name "com.sun.faces.vendor.Jetty6InjectionProvider:org.mortbay.jetty.plus.annotation.InjectionCollection" for service type "com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider"
09:03:51,375 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-8) JNDI bindings for session bean named UserFacadeBean in deployment unit subdeployment "GoodByeJohnEJB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" of deployment "GoodByeJohnEAR.ear" are as follows:

    java:global/GoodByeJohnEAR/GoodByeJohnEJB-1.0-SNAPSHOT/UserFacadeBean!za.co.gbj.UserFacadeService
    java:app/GoodByeJohnEJB-1.0-SNAPSHOT/UserFacadeBean!za.co.gbj.UserFacadeService
    java:module/UserFacadeBean!za.co.gbj.UserFacadeService
    java:global/GoodByeJohnEAR/GoodByeJohnEJB-1.0-SNAPSHOT/UserFacadeBean
    java:app/GoodByeJohnEJB-1.0-SNAPSHOT/UserFacadeBean
    java:module/UserFacadeBean

09:03:51,406 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named UserFacadeBean in deployment unit subdeployment "GoodByeJohnWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" of deployment "GoodByeJohnEAR.ear" are as follows:

    java:global/GoodByeJohnEAR/GoodByeJohnWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/UserFacadeBean!za.co.gbj.UserFacadeService
    java:app/GoodByeJohnWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/UserFacadeBean!za.co.gbj.UserFacadeService
    java:module/UserFacadeBean!za.co.gbj.UserFacadeService
    java:global/GoodByeJohnEAR/GoodByeJohnWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/UserFacadeBean
    java:app/GoodByeJohnWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/UserFacadeBean
    java:module/UserFacadeBean

09:03:51,577 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) Service status report
   New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.GoodByeJohnEAR."GoodByeJohnWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT".env/UserService (missing)
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.GoodByeJohnEAR."GoodByeJohnWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT"."env/za.co.gbj.UserController/userService" (missing)
```

Please assist!

Comment: Are you running it from an IDE ? If yes then expand the server twistie and see if both of them are actually deployed.Seems like war file is not there.Also at when do you get this error, when you start the server?

Comment: Can you provide more information of your annotations of `UserFacadeService` and `UserFacadeBean`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue might be that your WAR doesn't have a dependency for your EJB jar defined. It's best to define a Class-Path entry your WAR's META-INF/MANIFEST.MF for your EJB jar files if you have not.

You might also want to check your configuration file and make sure the `<ear-subdeployments-isolated />` tag is set to false.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0" >            
  <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
</subsystem>
```

There is also some decent documentation on [class loading in JBoss AS7](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7).

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure in your war, you have the file **META-INF/MANIFEST.MF**, and there has the line **Class-Path: GoodByeJohnEJB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar**,

Then in your UserController class, try to remove the mappedName, just add the EJB annotation.

Or, you can use this :

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
UserFacadeService userService = (UserFacadeService )ic.lookup("java:global/GoodByeJohnEAR/GoodByeJohnEJB-1.0-SNAPSHOT/UserFacadeBean");
```